# How to set default boolean false in formcontrol

Tags: angular, angular-material, ionic4, angular8, angular-forms

set default boolean false in formcontrol (primary field) ko

```
this.contactForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required]),
      contact: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required,Validators.minLength(10)]),
      email: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required,Validators.email]),
      primary: new FormControl('',[])
    });
```

HTML File :-
please see html file

```
<form [formGroup]="contactForm">
    <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" formControlName="primary" [value]="primary" [(ngModel)]="primary"> Make this primary </mat-checkbox>
  </form>
```

[image: console print img]

Comment: Why are you using a mixture of `formControlName`, `ngModel` and `value` at the same time? They aren't supposed to be combined together - you use `formControlName` if you're using Angular's Reactive Forms, `ngModel` for Angular's Forms and `value` for binding to `MatCheckBox`'s `value` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First argument of FormControl gets initial value, so you can easily write:

```
new FormControl(false, [...]);
```

Or it could be more complex if you need:

```
new FormControl({ value: false, disabled: true }, [...]);
```

Comment: It didn't set default value

Comment: Can you provide me what `console.log(this.contactForm.value)` returns? And how you implemented formcontrol in html?

Comment: please see updated question (please see image) console.log(this.contactForm.value) value

Comment: Please first fix your html file as described here https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms, then above code should be working as expected even for checkboxes and true/false values.

Comment: Anyway i guess, if you write console.log(this.contactForm.value) just below form group initializer, it should print the right value.

Comment: form group initializer is print on console is getting right default value  but when click on submit button it didn't getting default value

Comment: It means, when you fix the html it should be working fine :)

Comment: See @Edric comment above as well.

Comment: I fixes also @Edric comment

Answer (score 3):

You can use [patchValue()](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)  in your OnInit() function :

```
this.contactForm.patchValue({primary: false});
```

Comment: It didn't set default value

Comment: @keshavgodani  did you find the solution , i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: `{ email: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, ...) }`